# PHP query to write multiple arrays of random lengths to the same table in a MySQL database, without getting "Undefined offset" error

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to add all my random generated values (each saved in a different array), to the same table.

```
//Get the maximum nr of inputs, from the longest array.
$countMax = max(count($arrCA),count($arrZN),count($arrMP),count($arrEC),count($arrL),count($arrGP),count($arrNC),count($arrFS),count($arrNW))


require_once 'login.php';
$conn = new mysqli($hn, $un, $pw, $db);
if ($conn->connect_error) die($conn->connect_error);
//Add the values to the Database untill the maximum nr is reached.  
for($i = 0; $i<$countMax; $i++) {

    $query = "INSERT INTO Province
                    (CA,ZN,MP,EC,L,GP,NC,FS,NW) 
            VALUES('$arrCA[$i]','$arrZN[$i]','$arrMP[$i]',
                    '$arrEC[$i]','$arrL[$i]','$arrGP[$i]',
                    '$arrNC[$i]','$arrFS[$i]','$arrNW[$i]')";

    $result = $conn->query($query);
    if (!$result) die ("Database access failed: ".$conn->error);
}
```

The problem is now my PHP web-page says

> Notice: Undefined offset: 13 on line 135;

Any help on how to improve this script will be appreciated!

Comment: before `$query` execute you should check all variables . example `if(isset($arrCA[$i]))  {`

Comment: What is line 135?

Comment: If the arrays are of different length and you base your loop on the size of the largest array, using this method will always end up generating this error somewhere

Comment: @BilalAhmed Thank you, I will go try that. Also what will happen if the statement returns FALSE?

Comment: What would you enter into a column if there was nothing in one of these arrays for a specific occurance?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes and that is why I ask you guys for a better method...

Comment: @RiggsFolly These arrays will always have random values, that was generated previously in the script.

Comment: use array_pad to give each array the same amount of elements, eg $arrCA=array_pad($arrCA, $countMax , 0);http://php.net/array_pad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment you should check variable before `$query` execute .

```
if(!isset($arrCA[$i])){
 $arrCA[$i]="";
}
if(!isset($arrZN[$i])){
 $arrCA[$i]="";
}
```

and check all variables using `isset` function and then assign `query` to `$query` variable and execute the `query`

```
$query = "INSERT INTO Province
                    (CA,ZN,MP,EC,L,GP,NC,FS,NW) 
            VALUES('$arrCA[$i]','$arrZN[$i]','$arrMP[$i]',
                    '$arrEC[$i]','$arrL[$i]','$arrGP[$i]',
                    '$arrNC[$i]','$arrFS[$i]','$arrNW[$i]')";

    $result = $conn->query($query);
```

Comment: Thank you!! I see now what you mean. I have tried it and succeeded. So the error then was because I attempted to access a value in the array that does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Pad the arrays all to the size of the largest using your `$countMax` value. Then all arrays will be the same length.

All you need to check is that you are setting the default value, param 3 of `array_pad()` to a sensible value for that column, I use `0` as an example.

```
//Get the maximum nr of inputs, from the longest array.
$countMax = max(count($arrCA),count($arrZN),count($arrMP),
                count($arrEC),count($arrL),count($arrGP),
                count($arrNC),count($arrFS),count($arrNW))

// use a valid default to pad the ones that dont exist, i used 0 as example
$arrCA = array_pad($arrCA, $countMax , 0);
$arrZN = array_pad($arrZN, $countMax , 0);
$arrMP = array_pad($arrMP, $countMax , 0);
$arrEC = array_pad($arrEC, $countMax , 0);
$arrL  = array_pad($arrL, $countMax , 0);
$arrGP = array_pad($arrGP, $countMax , 0);
$arrNC = array_pad($arrNC, $countMax , 0);
$arrFS = array_pad($arrFS, $countMax , 0);
$arrNW = array_pad($arrNW, $countMax , 0);

require_once 'login.php';

$conn = new mysqli($hn, $un, $pw, $db);
if ($conn->connect_error) die($conn->connect_error);
//Add the values to the Database untill the maximum nr is reached.  
for($i = 0; $i<$countMax; $i++) {

    $query = "INSERT INTO Province
                    (CA,ZN,MP,EC,L,GP,NC,FS,NW) 
            VALUES('$arrCA[$i]','$arrZN[$i]','$arrMP[$i]',
                    '$arrEC[$i]','$arrL[$i]','$arrGP[$i]',
                    '$arrNC[$i]','$arrFS[$i]','$arrNW[$i]')";

    $result = $conn->query($query);
    if (!$result) die ("Database access failed: ".$conn->error);
}
```